# How to invert scipy.interpolate.interp1d behaviour

Tags: python, arrays, scipy, interpolation

From the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) of scipy.interpolate.interp1d:

> x and y are arrays of values used to approximate some function f: y = f(x). This class returns a function whose call method uses interpolation to find the value of new points.
>
> Parameters
>
> x(N,) array_like: A 1-D array of real values.
>
> y(…,N,…) array_like: A N-D array of real values. The length of y along the interpolation axis must be equal to the length of x.

So basically, it assumes that I have some `x` for which I have calculated multiple `y=f(x)` that I want to interpolate. But my case is exactly opposite: I have a single `y` array that I want to interpolate for many different `x` arrays. In other words, I have the situation:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

n_to_interpolate = 10

x = np.cumsum(np.random.rand(n_to_interpolate,100),axis=1)
y = np.linspace(0,1,100)

interp1d(x,y)
```

But this gives an error because the shapes do not match. Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Could you clarify this:  I have a single y array that I want to interpolate for many different x arrays. In other words?

Comment: @DaniMesejo I have calculated some output `y` with length 100. However, there are many possible inputs `x` with length 100 that match this output. For every single input `x`, I want to run `interp1d` (without a for loop) (and afterwards I will use it to interpolate)

Comment: `y = np.linspace(0,1,n_to_interpolate)`, I mean, you need have the same lengths of x and y vectors.

Comment: @Suthiro no this is not correct, I want to interpolate the 2nd axis of x with the y.

Comment: So you want 10 functions?

Comment: @DaniMesejo correct!

Comment: btw what was the issue with the for-loop did you try it and it was slow?

Comment: @DaniMesejo yes, in reality I have 1000s of inputs `x`

Comment: In the documentation it specifies that x must be a 1-d array

Comment: @DaniMesejo and that is exaclty the problem :(

Comment: Would you be willing to use something like numba?

Comment: @DaniMesejo yes.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to loop over the 1d slices of the `x` array.

If you only need a linear interpolation, `np.interp` is faster then `interp1d`

Comment: This is my current solution, but it is very slow. I use `np.interp` currently, but it has no vectorization whatsoever (so only one interpolation at a time). I went to `interp1d` because it can do multiple interpolations, but this unfortunately has the inverse behaviour of what I want